# problem with moving vector of array in c++23 on gcc 13.2

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector, move-constructor

I am getting a problem with my code. https://godbolt.org/z/9hdWrdPnG. Its a normal Trie implementation where I have used std::array to store indices of nodes into a std::vector which increases as new node elements are stored.
There is a strange behaviour when I don't reserve memory for vector of arrays in Trie constructor. As the capacity of vector changes, the array object would be moved inside new allocated space of vector, but the contents of array gets messed up. I am not sure its a problem with the code I implemented, or just behaviour of the containers in the library that I am overlooking.
I know that std::array move constructors are different wrt other containers move constructors, but I am not sure what would be right behaviour here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Trie {
    struct Node {
        Node() : child{}, words{0} {
            fill_n(child.begin(), 26, -1);
        }
        void print(ostream& oss) {
            for(auto&& x : child) oss << setw(2) << x << ' ';
            oss << words << endl;
        }
        array<int,26> child{};
        int words{0};
    };
    vector<Node> data{};
    Node root{};

public:
    Trie() : data{}, root{}{
        //data.reserve(32);
    }

    void print(ostream& oss = cerr) {
        root.print(oss);
        for(auto&& nd : data) nd.print(oss);
    }

    void insert(string word) {
        Node* node = &root;
        for (auto&& w : word) {
            int& i = node->child[w-'a'];
            if (i == -1) {
                cerr << "cap: (" << data.capacity();
                data.emplace_back(Node{});
                cerr << '/' << data.capacity() << ")\n";
                i = data.size() - 1;
            }
            node = &data[i];
        }
        ++node->words;
    }

    bool search(string word) {
        Node* node = &root;
        for (auto&& w : word) {
            int& i = node->child[w - 'a'];
            if (i == -1)
                return false;
            else {
                node = &data[i];
            }
        }
        return node->words > 0;
    }

    bool startsWith(string prefix) {
        Node* node = &root;
        for (auto&& w : prefix) {
            int& i = node->child[w - 'a'];
            if (i == -1)
                return false;
            else {
                node = &data[i];
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};


int main() {
    Trie obj;
    obj.insert("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

    cerr << obj.search("abcd") << ", " << obj.startsWith("abcd") << endl;
    obj.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have [undefined behavior](https://godbolt.org/z/3qr3safMP).

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself. Do you know how to use a debugger? Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Please make your questions self-contained, without the need to check external links (which might disappear or have their contents changed).

Comment: @DrewDormann, thanks. A change in capacity of vector requires that all elements are moved, so the contents should be intact. I don't see the problem when I reserve memory in advance or I replace array with vector of capacity 26. What would be the fix for this if I want to use std::array. I think something very specific related to array is happening here.

Comment: `int& i = node->child[w-'a']; data.emplace_back(Node{}); i = data.size() - 1;` Here `node` is a pointer to an element of `data`, and `i` is a reference to a subobject of that element. If `data.emplace_back(...)` triggers reallocation, all pointers and references to any elements and parts thereof get invalidated; `i` becomes a dangling reference, and assigning to it exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: OT: Please note that `w - 'a'` is not portable. It will not work on all encodings and all systems. (Though I'll admit that you will likely never come across a system which is not using ASCII.)